# In NestJS, how do I uniformly convert a field whose data type is time type into a timestamp format and then return it to the front end？

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Nestjs How can I convert date to Timestamp? (I have tried many methods but it doesn’t work, please help me)

This is the data type that I return now：

```
{
  "data": {
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "create_time": "2021-02-27T03:04:06.240Z"
     }
    ]
}
```

I hope to convert all dates into the following format

```
{
  "data": {
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "create_time": "1614395046"
     }
    ]
}
```

Although you can try to use the following methods to achieve, but I don’t want to do this, I hope there is a more elegant solution

```
  // Date.prototype.toJSON = (key) => {
  //   return moment(key).unix().toString()
  // };
```

ps：

Neither foreach nor gettime is what I want. How do I handle this data type uniformly in Nest

Answer (score 3):

In native JavaScript you can use the `Date` constructor to get an epoch in milliseconds.

```js
new Date('2021-02-27T03:04:06.240Z').getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply，I know this method, but I need to convert all date-type fields returned from the database to TIMESTAMP

Comment: Are you expecting to get them from the database like this or process the JSON after you receive it to change all the values?

Answer (score 1):

given your JSON, simply manipulate it to change the date to a timestamp:
and it looks like you have a number of elements in your JSON so:

```
var myDate = new Date();
for(var i=0;i<obj.data.results;i++){
    obj.data.results[i].create_time = myDate(obj.data.results[i].create_time).getTime();
}
```